# App makes device to restart

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My Xamarin.Forms application works on my Nexus 5 device and multiple Android emulators I tested it on. However, when I tried testing it on other real physical devices - Galaxy Note 4 and LG G4, the device restarts the moment I click on the app to open. I don't know what makes this happen or how to find a log/crash report/anything of that sort in order to find out what the issue is and would like to get some help with that.

Comment: plz sahre your code

Comment: Please post a [diagnostic build output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output).